# Kubernetes init container sysctl changes affecting containers under the POD

Tags: linux, kubernetes, linux-kernel

I made a change to sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time via init container. But i can see the changes to container under POD.How does this changes in initcontainer[BusyBox] affects container of a differenent image [Linux]?

Expectation is how Kubernetes init container sysctl changes affecting containers under the POD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time will be same between the init container and main container inside pod as it will share network namespace.  For more details please refer [documentation](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/kubernetes-pod-network-communications#:%7E:text=From%20a%20network%20standpoint%2C%20each,with%20each%20other%20over%20localhost.) on network namespace perspective

Comment: Thank Medayhal on clarification!